# Как правильно согласовать?

Tags: согласование, синтаксис

"Мой прекрасный секретарь Люба" или "моя прекрасная секретарь Люба"?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант обязателен лишь для официальных документов (хотя в них сложно представить подобную формулировку).

Answer (score 1):

Это мой прекрасный секретарь Люба. Это моя прекрасная секретарь Люба.

Но: моя прекрасная секретарь Люба опоздала.

При подлежащем — существительном мужского рода, называющем лицо по роду деятельности и в данном предложении относящемся к лицу женского пола, возможны обе формы: *Врач пришла / пришел. Педагог выступила / выступил с речью.* Такие колебания характерны для газетной, разговорной речи. Строгое грамматическое правило выбора родовой формы в сказуемом отсутствует, за исключением тех случаев, когда при существительном есть определение в форме женского рода: *Наша врач пришла. Новая секретарь ошиблась. Дело рассматривала районная судья.*

Comment: При всём уважении, этот параграф из РГ-80 описывает **другой** (хотя и смежный) вопрос грамматики.

Comment: Не другой. Если в предложении о Любе есть глагол (что вполне вероятно), то из двух данных возможен лишь вариант "моя прекрасная секретарь Люба".

Comment: Разве было дано *предложение*? Там никакой предикативности и в помине не было. :)

Comment: _Наша врач_ и _новая секретарь_ еще куда ни шло (хотя мне, например, режет слух), но вот _районная судья_ - совсем не ложится. Может. потому, что слово "судья" по форме похоже на слово женского рода.

Comment: "Районная судья" невозможно, но по другим причинам. "Районный судья -должность, не позволяющая собой манипулировать, а не некий судья, сведенный до уровня районного. В последнем случае "районнв судья вполне было бы возможно: красивая судья, опытная судья и проч.

Answer (score 0):

а) необособленное определение ставится в форме мужского рода (даже при наличии в предложении собственного имени): В журнале «Знамя» появился новый автор Н. Петрова. Уже известный читателям автор Н. Петрова предложила новую статью.

Поэтому Мой прекрасный секретарь Люба
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_89

Comment: Откуда такая категоричность?